# Reinterpret bits cast float ->int in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I need the GLSL equivalent of

```
float f; 
int   i = *(int *)&f;
```

I know that there is [floatBitsToInt()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/floatBitsToInt.xhtml) , but unfortunately it's in 3.3 GL version and upper. I need it for 3.0.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think that there is any practical way to emulate this in GLSL 1.30. However, since any real-world GPU supporting GL 3.0 also supports 3.3, I think your request is very questionable.

Comment: It's not about a hardware - it's about software dependencies I have to use.